# Carrierwave, is it possible to load images into manipulate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave

Is it possible to load an image into the manipulate! block in a Carrierwave uploader?

For example:

```
process :cover
def cover
  manipulate! do |img|
  # interesting manipulation code
  img = Magick::Image::read("#{Rails.root}/tmp/doc.jpg").first
  img
end
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Look at code [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb#L296) and [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L311) for detail information.

Don't forget to destroy passed image manually to release resources.